# compile_commands.json cannot be found

Tags: c++, json, cmake, visual-studio-code

I've struggled with this for an hour now and would love some help. I'm trying to use the `compile_commands.json` file with vs code and the cpp extension. Below is my `c_cpp_properties.json` file and the `compile_commands.json` file.

### c_cpp_properties.json

```
...
{
    "name": "Win32",
    "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++",
        "C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/mingw32",
        "C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/backward",
        "C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include",
        "C:/MinGW/mingw64/include",
        "C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include-fixed"
    ],
    "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "__GNUC__=6",
        "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
    ],
    "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/BlitzEngine/builds/Debug/compile_commands.json",
    "browse": {
        "path": [                    
            "C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include",
            "C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include-fixed",
            "C:/MinGW/mingw64/include"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
    }
}
...
```

### compile_commands.json

```
[
{
  "directory": "C:/Users/Emburn/Documents/Projects/BlitzEngine/builds/Debug",
  "command": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe   @CMakeFiles/BlitzEngine.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g   -o CMakeFiles\\BlitzEngine.dir\\src\\BlitzEngine.cpp.obj -c C:\\Users\\Emburn\\Documents\\Projects\\BlitzEngine\\src\\BlitzEngine.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/Emburn/Documents/Projects/BlitzEngine/src/BlitzEngine.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "C:/Users/Emburn/Documents/Projects/BlitzEngine/builds/Debug",
  "command": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe   @CMakeFiles/BlitzEngine.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g   -o CMakeFiles\\BlitzEngine.dir\\src\\main.cpp.obj -c C:\\Users\\Emburn\\Documents\\Projects\\BlitzEngine\\src\\main.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/Emburn/Documents/Projects/BlitzEngine/src/main.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "C:/Users/Emburn/Documents/Projects/BlitzEngine/builds/Debug",
  "command": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe   @CMakeFiles/BlitzEngine.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g   -o CMakeFiles\\BlitzEngine.dir\\src\\RenderWindow.cpp.obj -c C:\\Users\\Emburn\\Documents\\Projects\\BlitzEngine\\src\\RenderWindow.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/Emburn/Documents/Projects/BlitzEngine/src/RenderWindow.cpp"
}
]
```

I've tried using an absolute path without `${workspaceFolder}` but that didn't work either and every time I save the file it just says

```
"${workspaceFolder}/BlitzEngine/builds/Debug/compile_commands.json"
could not be found. Using 'includePath'
setting in c_cpp_properties.json
```

My directory tree is as such:

```
Projects
+-- .vscode
|   +-- c_cpp_properties.json
+-- BlitzEngine
|   +-- Debug
|   |   +-- compile_commands.json
+-- include
|   +-- <header_files>
+-- src
|   +-- <source_files>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you writing these by hand?  I thought standard practice for `compile_commands.json` is to have a tool (like `cmake`) generate it for you.

Comment: @StephenNewell It is generated by cmake. I'm just trying to make vscode find the file

Comment: You have "compileCommands.json" in your `c_cpp_properties.json` file, but the actual file is snake cased (i.e., `compile_commands.json`).

Comment: @StephenNewell oh woops. I just put it back to normal. I did that while trouble shooting it. It's still not working though

Comment: Your error message still shows the old path.  Also, it looks like you're using `workspaceFolder` instead of `workspaceRoot` (guessing based on your directory layout).

Comment: @StephenNewell Ah thank you I fixed that too now. And `workspaceRoot` is actually depreciated in current versions of vscode. It is recommended to use `workspaceFolder` instead.

Comment: @StephenNewell I actually just tried `workspaceRoot` just to see and it worked. So I guess now my question is where is `workspaceFolder` leading then? Also if you like you could post that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `workspaceFolder` listed in the `c_cpp_properties.json` [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md).  The examples there use `workspaceRoot`, which you have earlier in your configuration.

Comment: @Julia - That's what I get for answering questions while hockey is on :)

Comment: Link has changed to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference